# Exponential Function Approximation

Tags: approximation

Let $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ be known constants such that $n_1 + n_2 = n$. Moreover, let $0 \leq p_1, p_2 \leq 1-1/n$. Assume an exponential model $f(k) = n_1 p_1^k + n_2 p_2^k,\ k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I have access to points $y_k$ such that
$|y_k - f(k)| \leq \epsilon$.

> I would like to take the minimum number of points $y$ in
>   order to construct an approximation $\hat{f}$ of $f$ such that
>   $| \hat{f}(k) - f(k) | \leq \epsilon$, for every 
>   $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

We just need to approximate the first $O(n/\epsilon)$ points of $f$ because for $k \in \omega(n/\epsilon)$, $f(k)$ is approximately $0$ since $(1-\frac1n)^{n/\epsilon} \approx 
(1/e)^{1/\epsilon} \approx 0$.

The problem is of course trivial if we obtain $O(n)$ approximations:
$y_1\approx f(1),\ y_2 \approx f(2),\ \ldots,\ y_n \approx f(n), \ldots, y_{c n} \approx f(c n)$.

Since $f$ is an exponential decreasing function I am thinking 
of obtaining $\log(n)$ points 
\begin{equation*}
y_1  \approx f(1),\ y_2 \approx f(2),\ y_4 \approx f(4),\ y_8 \approx f(8),\ \ldots\ ,\  y_{2^i} \approx f(2^i)
\end{equation*}
because $f$ decreases rapidly in the beggining and slower for greater 
values of $k$.
Are there any references for such cases of function approximation ?